# Android Scroller: current velocity calculation

Tags: android, scroller

Some time ago I started to write some kind of a list view for my purposes and yesterday I became frustrated due to something strange happening with my scrolling behaviour.
I have read the source code of the default `android.widget.Scroller` class implementation and noticed that things were simplier than they seems to be. There are laws of kinematics taken as stone. Unfortunately, when I decided to increase deceleration at some point while flinging I noticed that current velocity was not always calculated correctly. After review of the Scroller source code I realized that the current velocity was always calculated incorrectly. There is a hiden method that calculates current velocity of the scroller:

```
/**
 * @hide
 * Returns the current velocity.
 *
 * @return The original velocity less the deceleration. Result may be
 * negative.
 */
public float getCurrVelocity() {
    return mVelocity - mDeceleration * timePassed() / 2000.0f;
}
```

As you can see there is `Vfinal = Vsource - a * t / 2`... but what is division by 2 for???
Since I have changed it to the phisically correct method

```
public float getCurrVelocity() {
    return mVelocity - mDeceleration * timePassed() / 1000.0f;
}
```

My sping effect works fine.

So the question is why there is division by 2? Or is it just a mistake since this method is hidden and wasn't called locally inside the Scroller class?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the Scroller class too, but I haven't evaluated the code as closely as you have.

I recommend trying the new android.widget.OverScroller class instead. It seems to handle various velocities more properly. It was added in API level 9, which is gingerbread.